# Check for local notifications settings from extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to check for the current Local Notifications settings inside a Cocoa Touch Framework used by an extension?

Usually I’d use

```
    var currentStatus:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
```

… but access to `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` is not available as extension safe API.

Any alternative?

Comment: Why do you want to reach the notification settings from the extension?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Swift, not sure if below is a good practice, I would make it a global function, just to make the call shorter:

```
// Or name it appCurrentStatus as you wish
func appCurrentUserNotificationSettings() -> UIUserNotificationSettings {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
}
```